# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing (M-1 relation)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transient

I know there is a lot of posts about this exception, but I am a beginner with using spring.  I've tried to solve the exception at without any result so far.  I need your help to solve it.

I have an employee table which has a foreign key for marital status id table(Many to One relation).
**The foreign key of marital status in employee table can be null**, when I try to insert an employee without selecting marital status from list in UI I got the below exception, but if I select a marital status from list it works fine.

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.nassar.model.MaritalStatus
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:489)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:295)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:305)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4027)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:527)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:234)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:163)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:554)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.add(Unknown Source)
at com.nassar.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployee(EmployeeController.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Employee Controller source

```
//////////////////////////////////Employee Controller//////////////////////////////////////
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/emp")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee){

    // employeeService calls employeeDAO 
    employeeService.add(employee); 

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-emp");

    modelAndView.addObject("department_list", departmentService.listAllDepartment());
    modelAndView.addObject("m_status_list", maritalStatusService.listAllMaritalStatus());

    modelAndView.addObject("employee", new Employee());

    return modelAndView;
}
...
}
```

Employee entity source

```
//////////////////////    Employee entity    //////////////////////
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

     @Id
     @Column(name="pk_id")
     @Basic(optional=false)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer employeeId;
     ...
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="fk_marital_status", referencedColumnName="id")
     private MaritalStatus fkMaritalStatus;
     ...
}
```

Marital Status source

```
//////////////////////    Marital Status entity    //////////////////////
@Entity
@Table(name = "marital_status")
public class MaritalStatus {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @Basic(optional=false)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Integer maritalStatusId;


     @Basic(optional=false)
     @Column(name="description")
     private String maritalStatusDescription;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="fkMaritalStatus")
     private List<Employee> employeeList;

}
```

EmployeeDAO source

```
 /////////////////////EmployeeDAO///////////////////////
 @Repository
 public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(Employee employee) {
        session.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
    }
...
}
```

this is the form used to insert an employee using jsp & spring form

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/emp/add"
    method="post" commandName="employee">
    <table title="Add Employee">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
  ...
        <tr>
            <td>Marital Status</td>
            <td><form:select path="fkMaritalStatus.maritalStatusId" >
                <form:option value="">Select Marital status</form:option>
                <c:forEach items="${m_status_list}" var="m_status">
                    <form:option value="${m_status.maritalStatusId}">${m_status.maritalStatusDescription}</form:option>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
 ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I found that if marital status not selected from the list, it creates new instance of MaritalStatus and without initializing it's instance variables and try to insert it to DB, but it fails, because description of marital status do not accept null value.

I did not know how to solve it in standard why till now, but found workaround for it :)  which is :

```
if(employee.getFkMaritalStatus().getMaritalStatusId() == null)
        employee.setFkMaritalStatus(null);

session.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
```

Comment: Can you create a `toString()` method on Employee entity, and print it just before you saved it into database

Comment: Yes i did, and it prints all employee instance variable values correctly as I entered them. And Fk_marital_status = null, if not selected from list

Comment: What employeeId value was set before you save it?